# configure MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter getting BeanCreationException

Tags: spring-mvc

Error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in class path resource 
[...../spring/controller/PsvJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class]:
 No matching factory method found: factory bean 'psvJackson2HttpMessageConverter'; 
factory method 'converter()'. 
Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.
```

And here is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class PsvJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

     @Override
     public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
      converters.add(converter());
      converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
      converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
      super.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
     }

     @Bean
     MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
         MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
         ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
         converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return converter;
        }
}
```

Don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing which you can do:

1. Create a configuration class, which registers/maps the converters.
2. Create custom converter class.

For example, here is the config class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new CustomMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

and here is the converter class:

```
public class CustomMappingConverter extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {


    public CustomMappingConverter(final ObjectMapper objectMapper){
        super(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, new MediaType("application", "*+json"), new MediaType("application", "jsonp"));
    }

    private String jsonPrefix;


    public CustomMappingConverter() {
        this(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build());
    }


    public void setJsonPrefix(final String jsonPrefix) {
        this.jsonPrefix = jsonPrefix;
    }


    public void setPrefixJson(final boolean prefixJson) {
        jsonPrefix = prefixJson ? ")]}', " : null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void writePrefix(final JsonGenerator generator, final Object object) throws IOException {
        if (jsonPrefix != null) {
            generator.writeRaw(jsonPrefix);
        }
        final String jsonpFunction =
                object instanceof MappingJacksonValue ? ((MappingJacksonValue) object).getJsonpFunction() : null;
                if (jsonpFunction != null) {
                    generator.writeRaw("/**/");
                    generator.writeRaw(jsonpFunction + "(");
                }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeSuffix(final JsonGenerator generator, final Object object) throws IOException {
        final String jsonpFunction =
                object instanceof MappingJacksonValue ? ((MappingJacksonValue) object).getJsonpFunction() : null;
                if (jsonpFunction != null) {
                    generator.writeRaw(");");
                }
    }

}
```